# Broken screen on Nikon D3. How can I fix it?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, equipment-damage

I've a Nikon D3. One day unexpectedly the rear LCD screen has stopped working. It shows only white lines, as in the attached pic.
I've changed 4 screens:

- the first: shows only few light green lines
- the second: shows a little more lines, but this time are white
- the third (maybe the only broken screen): works only the backlight
- the fourth: works like the second (is the one of the pic)

If I use HDMI it seems to work fine.

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong?

[image]

Comment: The problem could be upstream in some connector or electronics.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by, "I've changed 4 screens"?

Comment: The first one is the original screen that broke during a shooting. After that I bought three other screen from China.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Various copies of the same (active electronic) component working flawed in different manners each" tends to be a telltale sign of either:

- some signal lines being disconnected, leaving inputs not connected to anything (due to tolerance or design revisions, a "floating" input can be interpreted differently by each copy)
- marginal power supply to the component (each copy will have different exact power draw, making a failing power supply react differently)
- marginal signal quality on some line (upstream component sending the signal is failing. Again, interpretation of marginal signal is copy-dependent).

Answer (score 1):

This camera is not meant to be consumer-repairable. When you face a problem like this, send it into a Nikon repair center for repair.

Answer (score 1):

You can't fix the screen, because it apparently isn't the screen that is broken, but rather something else that provides the signal to the screen.